# UITableView DidSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a table view with a few items (all text). When the user clicks the row I want that text in that cell to be added to an array.

How Do I grab the text out of the cell?

I already Have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Is there a simple line I can use to grab the text out the cell that the user clicks?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use [`UITableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrowatindexpath)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm still in iOS7!

Comment: Nope. A lot of examples always dequeue and construct a new cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. So if you call it, you will not get the same cell that was returned when the framework called it to display the cells.

Comment: As long as `-(void)tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called as the result of UI interaction it will contain the correct the cell. Yes, you can and should reuse cells but that change will not affect this method.

Comment: The previous comment about dequeueing cells is confusing the `UITableViewDataSource` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with the method on `UITableView`.

Answer (score 6):

It's the inverse of what you did in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
 [myArray addObject: [datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can find most answers to questions like this in the Apple documentation. For this case, look under [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and you will see a section header: Accessing Cells and Sections. This give you the following method:

```
– cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Now use this to access the cell, and then use get the text from the cell (if you're unsure how, look under the [UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

All together, your method might look something like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
    [myArray addObject:cellText];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My first guess would be getting the index, [indexPath row]; then fetching the data from your datasource ( an array or core data ) rather than directly from the table itself.

Answer (score 2):

Swift Version:

```
let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
let cellText: String = cell.textLabel.text
```