# iOS selecting cell

Tags: ios, cell, selection

This might be really easy to answer but I've searched the net, stack and books but cannot find what I need.

Basically I have a really noddy app with a table, the table has 5 sections and each section has about 5 rows, all I need is for some code to put in the Didselectrow procedure to tell me what cell was selected and then do something -

so if cell 2 then display map etc.

Comment: what have you tried to do? a search here for [UITableView] select row has around 4000 results. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404922/uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath) seems close to what you want, but you'll need more detail to get a good answer

Comment: for example if you want to show may on selecting of third row of second section then you have to write the following code and similalry ......  if (indexPath.section==1) { if (indexPath.row==2) { //Show Map } }.............perhaps it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The selected cell is indicated by the index path parameter that you get in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. There's a category on NSIndexPath that gives you `-section` and `-row` methods; use those to determine the selected row and then take whatever action ou want based on that.