# iOS - Clickable UITableView with Custom Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Good day! I have an app that has UITableView with Custom Cell in it. What i want to do is when i click on a specific row it will do an action based on what is the text on that row or cell if possible. For example. lets say this is a tableview.

```
Flowers      12      Red
Meat         30      Dry
Mouse        10      Alive
Pen          12      Black
```

Then i clicked on the Meat row and i have a blank text box, it will show the text "Meat" in the Textbox or label. is that possible? thanks!

Comment: If you questions is whether it is possible the answer is **yes**.

Comment: go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404922/uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath, you will find your answer

Comment: why is my cell.textLabel.text is null? how can i change it to what ever row i click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do something like this:

Remember to have a datasource and a delegate of `UITableView` and declare your `UITextField` as a `mainTextField` property.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    mainTextField.text = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

If you need a more complex structure, you can create `UIButtons` for each row and with a `UITableViewCell` subclass with a custom delegate you can catch the events within a custom cell.

Comment: i will change the mainTextField.text to my own UITextfield right? i tried that but nothing happens to the textfield

Comment: You have to both get sure the method is called, the `cell.textLabel.text` is not nil and the textField you'r re referencing to exists. As simple as that

Comment: im trying to change also the cell.textLabel.text to my own cell textlable for the category meat. but it has an error, by the way im using this method to populate all my cell textlabel `cell.URN.text = [[self.ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: the cell.textLabel.text is Null, how can i change it?

Comment: @user3202533 You have to set it correctly in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 0):

add tags to subviews and put tapgesture for cell, and then in tapgesture target u can acces those views based on tags by subclassing uitableviewcell based on tapgesture tag...